# How to prevent Post from being cancelled with multiple update Panels

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have 2 user controls in differing update panels:
[image]

uc:Test is simply a button w/ a label:
[image]

When I click the button I run the following logic:
[image]

Because there are 2 instances of this user control, if I click the button from the first user control, wait 5 seconds, then click the button from the second user control, the first post is cancelled and only the second post properly executes. This results in the page not rendering correctly:
[image]

This also happens if the update mode of the update panels are conditional.

Is there a way to prevent the initial button click post from cancelling when the second button post is triggered?

Comment: See my answer + the new edit. As I show, update panels do not prevent and stop post-backs, but only do what is called a partial page post-back. As such, two buttons can't run code behind at the same time - only one can.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule?

If you have 2 (or even more) update panels on a given web form?

Clicking on a button, or causing a post-back in one panel will trigger the other panel to also post back.

Might not fix this issue, but use this tag for the update panel:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"
       UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

So, by adding UpdateMode="Conditional", then both panels will not be posted back. As noted, might not fix your issue - but worth a try.

You also don't (as a general rule) need to use the post-back triggers. Any old plane jane button, or control that cases a post-back should suffice. But as noted, such buttons will cause other update panels to post-back also - adding the above UpdateMode prevents this.

## Edit:

Having stated the above? A update panel does NOT prevent a post-back. It only does what we call a part page post-back (partial postback).

And the page load event will fire, and much of the page lifecycle still occurs when you use these partial post-backs.

So, just like any plane jane button on a form? if you click another button, then the page is posted back again. Thus, if the first button is not finished, then hitting any other button on the page - including any old button outside of the two panels, or even ones inside? You STILL causing a post-back (a partial one).

So, this code of yours:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Not clicked";
    }
```

That code will run if a button is clicked inside a panel, or outside of one.

Perhaps you want this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        Label1.Text = "Not clicked";
        }
    }
```

The above code will thus only run on first page load. However, above is 100% separate from the fact that a button click will cause a page post back, and page load to run each time. And this ALSO occurs (page load runs) even when you use/have update panels.

If you looking to have two buttons run seperate code, and even do so without the first button not having finished?

Then you have to adopt ajax calls (web method calls), since a page post-back really does not allow a 2nd button to start running until the first button is done.

While use of the update panel "looks" like a post-back did not occur? One still does - it only a partial page post-back, but page load for example even runs on button clicks - even one's inside of a update panel.

## Edit2: using ajax

Since as I noted, you can't have the two buttons run code. Clicking on one button will cause a page post back (partial page post back), and that will cancel the running of the first button.

So, assume we want two buttons. We click on one (or the ohter). Each will call some code behind. And when done, we update the form.

So, say this simple markup (two buttons)

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Process 1 click" CssClass="btn"
            OnClientClick="Process1();return false;" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>

        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Process 2 click" CssClass="btn"
            OnClientClick="Process2();return false;" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>


        <script>

            function Process1() {
                $('#Label1').text("Running - please wait")

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UpanelTest.aspx/Process1",
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (myresult) {
                        // put result of method call into lable 1
                        // ajax data is ALWAYS ".d" - its a asp.net thing!!!
                        $('#Label1').text(myresult.d)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                    }
                });
            }


            function Process2() {

                $('#Label2').text("Running - please wait")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "UpanelTest.aspx/Process2",
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (myresult) {
                        // put result of method call into lable 2
                        // ajax data is ALWAYS ".d" - its a asp.net thing!!!
                        $('#Label2').text(myresult.d)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
```

On the web page, code behind, lets fake a 3 second delay for each one.

eg this:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Process1()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Process2()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

So, now when we run this, we can click on either button - both of their code behind will run:

[image]

Above client side assumes jQuery is installed.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I do already know I can use the web methods for this but was trying to take advantage of the update panels to try and trigger ajax similar w/o dealing w/ jquery / javascript. The video is definitely what I was trying for though.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what the button + panel does.  If the button is to run some code that takes time then you could launch a process (new) - but that assumes you not trying to update the page - this would occur faster than user could click another button.

Comment: I guess you're right. If the process is quick. This page is fairly large that I'm trying to name use of this on with multiple ucs that update the page. Many ucs are in an update panel so that's why I thought to verify that this want an issue. However it might be a necessary evil.

Comment: Update panels are perhaps one of my favorte features (and this is dispite a lot of people who lament update panels. Update panels can result in some asynchronous operations, but for the most part a update panel still does cause a page post-back, and even the page load event fires. So, they in effect hide post-backs, but do not prevent them. And with a new post-back, then you will kill the current running code and button.